# Parallel processing to run multiple files when some contain errors

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I wish to run each `R` file in a folder using parallel processing.  Some of the `R` files contain intentional errors.  These errors appear to cause the parallel processing to stop once the first error is encountered.  Is there a way to get `R` to continue running through all of the files in the folder returning results for each file that does not contain an error?

Here is the `R` code that tries to run each of seven files in a folder.  Three of the seven files contain an error and should not run, but I would like to get the results for the four files that do not contain an error.  The parallel processing code only returns results for two files, not four files.

```
setwd('C:/Users/mark_/Documents/simple R programs/')

library(parallel)

detectCores()
#[1] 12

#make a cluster
my.cluster <- makeCluster(3)

folderName <- 'run_all_these3'
files <- list.files(folderName, full.names=TRUE)

parSapply(my.cluster, files, source)

stopCluster(my.cluster)
```

Here are the seven files in the folder `run_all_these3`.  The files differ only in the `seed`, the name of the output `CSV` file and in that three of the files contain `summ` as an incorrect specification of `sum`.  Output `CSV` files are only returned for two of the four files that contain no errors.

I am running `R` on a `Windows 10` laptop.

File: `run1.R`

```
set.seed(1234)
N <- 1000000000
my.stuff <- sample(1000, N, replace = TRUE)
my.sum <- sum(my.stuff)
print(my.sum)
write.csv(my.sum, file='my.sum1.csv', row.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE)
```

File: `run2.R`

```
set.seed(4444)
N <- 1000000000
my.stuff <- sample(1000, N, replace = TRUE)
my.sum <- sum(my.stuff)
print(my.sum)
write.csv(my.sum, file='my.sum2.csv', row.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE)
```

File: `run3.R`

```
set.seed(4321)
N <- 1000000000
my.stuff <- sample(1000, N, replace = TRUE)
my.sum <- summ(my.stuff)
print(my.sum)
write.csv(my.sum, file='my.sum3.csv', row.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE)
```

File: `run4.R`

```
set.seed(1111)
N <- 1000000000
my.stuff <- sample(1000, N, replace = TRUE)
my.sum <- sum(my.stuff)
print(my.sum)
write.csv(my.sum, file='my.sum4.csv', row.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE)
```

File: `run5.R`

```
set.seed(2222)
N <- 1000000000
my.stuff <- sample(1000, N, replace = TRUE)
my.sum <- summ(my.stuff)
print(my.sum)
write.csv(my.sum, file='my.sum5.csv', row.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE)
```

File: `run6.R`

```
set.seed(2121)
N <- 1000000000
my.stuff <- sample(1000, N, replace = TRUE)
my.sum <- summ(my.stuff)
print(my.sum)
write.csv(my.sum, file='my.sum6.csv', row.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE)
```

File: `run7.R`

```
set.seed(3434)
N <- 1000000000
my.stuff <- sample(1000, N, replace = TRUE)
my.sum <- sum(my.stuff)
print(my.sum)
write.csv(my.sum, file='my.sum7.csv', row.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `foreach` to control how to handle errors.

```
library(doParallel)
registerDoParallel(my.cluster <- makeCluster(3))
files <- c("doesnotexist.R")
foreach(file = files, .errorhandling = "remove") %dopar% {
  source(file)
}
stopCluster(my.cluster)
```

You can use `.combine` to combine the results (`c`, `cbind`, etc.), otherwise it returns a list by default.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `try(source(file, ...))` or `tryCatch(source(file, ...), error = function(e) NULL)` (returns `NULL` when there's an error), e.g.

```
parSapply(my.cluster, files, function(file, ...) try(source(file, ...)))
```

or

```
parSapply(my.cluster, files, function(file, ...) {
  tryCatch(source(file, ...), error = function(e) NULL)
})
```